# Adding a line break inside a list (or otherwise distinguishing it)

Tags: lists, memoir, description, quotation

With the code below (a tiny snippet from a book) the example quotation for the word Agerasia starts on the same line with the word itself.  I don't think the result makes a clear enough distinction between the main text and the quote. I thought of starting on a new line but \ gives an error "there is no line to end".

MWE Main file

```
\documentclass{memoir}
% \let\providelength\relax
\title{Interesting words}
\author{Peter Flom}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[marginpar]{todo}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{varioref}
% \let\providelength\relax

%% A convenience command, for typesetting the
%% word and pronunciation

%\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\medskip\noindent{\Large\textbf{#1} (#2)\par}}
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\medskip\noindent{\Large\textbf{#1} \normalsize{#2} \par}}



%\newcommand{\sclabel}[1]{\normalfont\scshape #1}
\newcommand{\sclabel}[1]{\leavevmode{\normalfont\scshape #1}}
%% Less spacing around lists
\firmlists

\begin{document}

    % \include{Intro}
     \include{Peopletest}
urces}
    
    \end{document}
```

and here is peopletest

```
\chapter{Words describing people}\label{C:People}


  \entry{Agerasia}{Age erase ee ya} \label{Agerasia} %On Medium %From OED Brought back
   \begin{flexlabelled}{sclabel}{0pt}{0.5em}{0.5em}{*}{\leftmargin}
      \item[Definition]
      \textit{n.} Youthful appearance in an old person, but not through artificial means (such as plastic surgery).
      \item[Etymology]
      From Greek combining \textit{a-} (not) \textit{geras} (age) and \textit{ia} via Latin \textit{agerasia},
      \item[Anti-thesaurus] \leavevmode
        \begin{description}
           \item[Appearance] -- which has nothing to do with youthfulness
           \item{Neanimophism} -- (See neanimorphism \vpageref{Neanimorphism}).
           \item[Visual aspect] -- see above
        \end{description}
      \item[Usage]
      See the example, below.
      \item[Examples]
      \begin{quote}

        Although many people go to extreme lengths to appear young, some are blessed with agerasia.
      \end{quote}
      \item[Frequency]
      Ngram viewer found no uses until 1953; now it's very rare indeed, about 1 in 6.5 billion words and the OED notes that it is ``chiefly in dictionaries''.
  \end{flexlabelled} \vspace{0.5in}
```

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks.